# Is it possible to take date from excel & upload some rows in selenium java webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

I have one excel Input files & I want to Upload data from excel automatically in Selenium java webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. So what you have to do is 1st read data from Excel. You can use [Apache POI](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi) library for this.

Once you've read the data from Excel then you can use that data like how you would use normal Java String's with Selenium.

Below are a couple of links for getting you started:

[Guru99](https://www.guru99.com/all-about-excel-in-selenium-poi-jxl.html)
[ToolsQA](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/data-driven-testing-excel-poi/)